Error while deploying gcloud update command for EventArc trigger on GCS bucket
I am getting the following error while running the command to update existing google cloud eventarc trigger for a Cloud Service application.
ERROR: (gcloud.eventarc.triggers.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request was invalid: missing required attribute 'type' in trigger.event_filters
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest fieldViolations: field: trigger.event_filters
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo requestId: 120f43d9f5c9aba4

The command that I am running is to check whether a trigger exists, if so to update it as shown below -
# Check if the Eventarc trigger exists
EXISTING_TRIGGER=$(gcloud eventarc triggers list --location=$REGION --filter="name:$TRIGGER_NAME" --format="value(name)")

if [ -n "$EXISTING_TRIGGER" ]; then
  echo "Trigger exists. Updating the trigger..."
  # Update the existing trigger
  gcloud eventarc triggers update $TRIGGER_NAME \
    --location=$REGION \
    --service-account=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
    --destination-run-service=$SERVICE_NAME \
    --destination-run-region=$REGION \
    --event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
    --event-filters="bucket=$BUCKET_NAME"
else
  echo "Trigger does not exist. Creating a new trigger..."
  # Create a new trigger
  gcloud eventarc triggers create $TRIGGER_NAME \
    --location=$REGION \
    --service-account=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
    --destination-run-service=$SERVICE_NAME \
    --destination-run-region=$REGION \
    --event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
    --event-filters="bucket=$BUCKET_NAME"
fi

The create event part is working but when I re-execute the command it's failing with the above error. On looking through google documentation - triggers-update, I see that event-filters are fields that can be passed and updated. Can someone guide me on what is going wrong here?
The alternative way to achieve this is (as per the chatbots) to delete existing trigger and then create. I don't have problem with that approach but just wanted to know why update isn't working.

I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided answer has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further

Eventarc triggers withgoogle.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized  Occurs when a new object is created, or an existing object is overwritten and a new generation of that object is created.  Matches are made on the following values from the audit log entry:
serviceName: the service that wrote the audit log
methodName: the operation that is being audited
resourceName: the resource that is being audited.
Go to Logging > Logs Explorer in Cloud Console. The Query results section lists the most recently generated logs. The Query builder section can be used to filter through logs. For more information on this issue refer to this documentation.

Hey @Supriya, Thanks for the response. The Cloud Event Logs have been disabled for our project. We need to go with the type of object finalized. I did look at the existing trigger in Cloud Service to edit and I see that both the bucket name and the type are disabled. This could be why the update is not working as well. I will need to go with the pattern of drop and recreate.
